# AWS SES, S3 email backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I am using SES+ S3 bucket.
I created the email backup through SES to S3 bucket.
So, Does S3 stores the email which I am sending to other? or only save that mail which I receive.

I think it stores both. But when I sent a mail. Then I didn't found it on S3. What can be the error.

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxXIpPZzMd0

Comment: SES doesn't store outgoing emails. only incoming

Comment: if you are  using ses from some kind of backend service you can run a lambda and store the details into   s3 bucket or use event bridge service which generates event when ses send email and s trigger lambda

Comment: Jatin Actually i am followed this link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxXIpPZzMd0 and the emails are started saving in S3, I want to make sure that it stores outgoing emails or not? Or i might have done some mistake in set up so that out going mails are not saving